# Does not work Ajax in comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to get new comments to update with ajax instead of a page reload. I need to press F5, and I see a new comment. But ajax does not work. Any ideas, please?

```
Started POST "/posts/3/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-28 01:37:19
+0300 Processing by CommentsController#create as JS Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"commenter"=>"Test", "body"=>"test"},
"commit"=>"Create Comment", "post_id"=>"3"} Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT 
"posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3],
["LIMIT", 1]] (0.4ms)  BEGIN SQL (14.9ms)  INSERT INTO "comments"
("commenter", "body", "post_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES
($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["commenter", "Test"], ["body",
"test"], ["post_id", 3], ["created_at", "2017-10-27 22:37:19.855603"],
["updated_at", "2017-10-27 22:37:19.855603"]] (28.1ms)  COMMIT
Rendering comments/create.js.coffee Rendered
comments/_comment.html.erb (1.7ms) Rendered comments/create.js.coffee
(470.8ms) Completed 200 OK in 542ms (Views: 479.4ms | ActiveRecord:
44.0ms)
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end

end
```

_comments_html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <% if admin_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', 
                [comment.post, comment],
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

create.js.coffee

```
$('.comment:last').after '<%= j render @comment %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few things wrong here.

First, you need to assign a application-wide unique id to your form. You'll use this later. Something, perhaps, like:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], remote: true, id: 'new-post-comment-form') do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Then, in `show.js.coffee` (for your post) you'll need some javascript that handles the successful submission of this form. Something like:

```
$('#new-post-comment-form').on 'ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) =>
  $('.comment:last').after(data)
```

Naturally, you're doing `$(document).ready` or the turbolinks equivalent (I forget how the turbolinks version goes because I turn turbolinks off in all of my apps) so that the above javascript loads.

Now, in your `CommentsController`, you need to actually do something with your `format.js`. In particular, you need to render some html so that data (above) contains a blob of html:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
      format.js { render @comment }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end

end
```

You might need to fiddle around with that `render @comment`, I'm not sure.

That may be incomplete. And, I didn't do any testing. But, hopefully that gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: I think everything should be simpler. I try to draw an analogy with this example: https://github.com/artemave/railjax-demo . But I can not do it. :(